# pip connection failure - cannot fetch index base URL

Tags: python, ip, pip

I can not neither install python packages via pip command and nor join the url http://pypi.python.org/ from my network subnet however When I connect to another network with same computer but different IP and subnet, I can install packages and join url.
I get the error message "Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/" 
when I do pip install.
I think this is something with the IP-ban issue becuase it was working previously.
Is there anyone had an experience like this before?

Comment: Could you be going through a proxy?  I have often got a similar message when my authentication details are incorrect.

Comment: What happens if you try to enable `--use-mirrors`?

Answer (score 1):

solution?:

```
user@host:~$export HTTP_PROXY="$http_proxy"
```

short answer: lowercase $http_proxy needs to be uppercase $HTTP_PROXY

long answer:
I was getting this error also.  Checked netstat -ant and it showed 
"SYN SENT" to [pypi.python.org] port 80.  But why?? My $http_proxy server clearly sends other traffic to another IP and port 8080?!  It's set globally and doesn't matter whether user is root or otheruser, so sudo -E solution doesn't play.

case sensitivity is not checked for environmental variables in pip versions 1.0 -> 1.3.1--at least for the os.environ.get() call for string HTTP_PROXY.  Not exactly a 'bug' but does conflict with other installed software like Google Chrome that use lowercase or case insensitive.

if netstat shows traffic to port 80 of some IP "not-your-proxies-IP", one solution is just to modify pip/download.py to look for lowercase env var 'http_proxy'.  Or, make sure that you have both $http_proxy and $HTTP_PROXY set in your environment.

Here's my test:

```
user@host:~$ grep -R HTTP_PROXY /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/*

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py:            
proxystr = os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY', '')

Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> proxystr = os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY', '')
>>> proxystr
''

Now I change HTTP_PROXY to http_proxy and the same snippet of download.py returns the value of my proxy

>>> proxystr = os.environ.get('http_proxy', '')
>>> proxystr
'http://proxyserver.mydomain.com:8080/'
```